# jQuery fade is not smooth the first time, but works after that

Tags: jquery

I have this code that fades the body of a page when the login button is clicked.  It has kind of 'hiccup' where is pauses with the outline of the textboxes still showing the first time this is run when I run the project.  If i do it again in the same session it works beautifully.

Is there a way to make this work right the first time?

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Web Portal - Login</title>
    <link href="~/css/common.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {



        $('#btnLogin').click(function () {
            $("body").fadeOut('2000');

        });


    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: make a jsfiddle where you can reproduce the problem, there is not much wrong in the code except #btnLogin and #txtUsername doesn't exist and jQuery version from dark ages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explanation

It's really difficult to reproduce a problem that most likely has to do with your personal browser, settings, computer etc.

You could be loading your JQuery script first, and after that, it's cached. The other thing that might be an issue, is that you've got a heavy document, loaded with fancy stuff that just takes up a lot of load time, and really makes the `.fadeOut` do a run for it's money.

[Here are some easy steps](http://www.tvidesign.co.uk/blog/improve-your-jquery-25-excellent-tips.aspx) to increase performance with JQuery

---

## Solution

- Try to [increase your performance](http://www.tvidesign.co.uk/blog/improve-your-jquery-25-excellent-tips.aspx) with JQuery.
- What browser are you using? IE, for example, is generally slow and inefficient in comparison with browsers like Firefox, Chrome or Opera.
- What are your computer specs? Is it a thin client with minimal CPU available?
- [I've set up this page](http://jsfiddle.net/BuVJ3/3/), nothing fancy, but it's a good way to see if it's your own page that's bothering you, or if it's the browser, or whatnot. If it doesn't do you any good, load up your page on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) yourself and see if you can reproduce it (make sure you select JQuery as  your framework).
- Try to put a wrapper inside the body, around the entire content and do a `.fadeOut()` on that instead, see if it makes any difference.

---

## Final thoughts

Like I said, it's difficult to help you with this, because it's very individual.
My best bet is that you're using the naughty **[Internet](http://css-tricks.com/ie-css-bugs-thatll-get-you-every-time/) [Explorer](http://www.impressivewebs.com/avoiding-problems-with-javascript-getelementbyid-method-in-internet-explorer-7/)** with lots of issues. :)

Comment: @RonaldMcDonald When you say "we", do you mean "my company"? If you're making a web application for your company, you shouldn't be using animations or anything fancy. Just the basics, for performance. As stated in the above answer, it's probably the browser that's causing it. I don't know the reason why you're hiding the body, and I couldn't think of any reason why you would in the first place, but instead of doing that, why not put an overlay element that covers the entire page, effectively hiding the body?